# Charging iphone without USB

Tags: usb, battery-charging, wire, telephone, iphone

I am looking to charge my iphone using a thermoelectric power generation device. The thermoelectric generator device has positive and negative leads, and I have tried connecting the wires from the USB cable (which I cut open and spliced) directly but no luck. I AM NOT LOOKING TO USE THE USB AND PLUG IT INTO A WALL/COMPUTER.

The thermoelectric generator device produces about .5 Watts and 1 amp.

Is it likely that the phone is not charging because the power supply is too low? Or is likely that the wire connection is poor? Does the power supply have to supply 2.1 Amps and 5 Volts for the phone to charge?

Thanks.

Comment: 0.5 Watts and 1 amp means your voltage is about 0.5V, which is 10 times lower than you phone needs.

Answer (score 4):

That's not going to work.

An iPhone needs a minimum of 5V / 500 mA to charge. This comes out to 2.5W, which is five times higher than the output of your TEG.

Answer (score -2):

It's can't be charge due to there's no  data wire has been connected,only + and - connections can't be charge the ipnone,
You should connect data port also.either you can Short both TX and RX (Middle 2 wire)of charging cable from USB side's.